# Formatting a data value with content using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a price slider, and upon hover it shows a "tooltip" of the slide price. The value changes in the tooltip when sliding along the slider. I wanted to add the £ sign to the values in the tooltip. I've managed to do this but the position of the £ needs correcting as it currently site like this: "250£ : £750". Take a look at the bootply I,ve mocked up showing this - http://bootply.com/72212

```
            if (this.range) {
                this.tooltipInner.text(
                    this.formater(this.value[0]) + 
                    '£ : £' + 
                    this.formater(this.value[1])
                );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
this.tooltipInner.text(
   '£' + this.formater(this.value[0]) + ' : £' + this.formater(this.value[1])
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I just don't understand the question, but could it be as trivial as

```
this.tooltipInner.text(
    '£' +
    this.formater(this.value[0]) + 
    ' : £' + 
    this.formater(this.value[1])
)
```

?